# What kind of exceptions can formatted output operators standard iostream objects throw?

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream, std

(1) Given an arbitrary variable `x` of a fundamental (possibly CV-qualified) type `X`, and

(2) a formatted output statement in the form of

```
outputStream << x;
```

where `outputStream` is any of the standard `<iostream>` output streams (`cout`, `cerr`, `clog`, `wcout`, `wcerr`, `wclog`):

**What restrictions does the C++11 standard imply on the types of exceptions that may be thrown from the statement (2)?** Suppose I want to write as precise `catch` matches as possible, and not limit myself to catching `std::exception`.

For example, should I also test for `std::bad_alloc` or any other exceptions from `<stdexcept>`, or are all exceptions limited to `ios_base::failure`?

```
try {
    outputStream << x;
} catch (/* ??? */) { /* ... */ }
} catch (/* ??? */) { /* ... */ }
// ... ???
```

PS: Please lets keep this a toolchain and platform agnostic, strict C++11 question. Comments like "Why the &#$% do you want to write code like this?" are not constructive. I just want to know what kind of exceptions to expect in the worst standards-compliant case. Thanks! :)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this description](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/failure/) **`std::ios_base::failure`** is the base class for exceptions thrown by all elements of the standard input/output library, including classes derived from `std::ios_base` such as`std::istream` and `std::ostream` (and hence `std::cin`, `std::cout` etc). However, be warned that this does not include classes from other standard libraries, e.g. `std::basic_ostringstream` from `<sstream>` may also throw exceptions from its allocator.

However, **by default** no exceptions are thrown. On error the `std::ios_base::eofbit`, `std::ios_base::failbit` and/or `std::ios_base::badbit` bits are set on the stream's internal error state flags using the `std::ios::setstate()` method on the respective stream object. According to [this description](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/) if an error state flag is set a respective exception is thrown if and only if the current exception mask of the stream has the respective flag bit set. By default, the current exception mask has no bits set and hence no exceptions are thrown. One can utilize the `std::ios::exceptions()` method to change this exception mask and make the stream throw exceptions on error.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/)

> Exception safety Basic guarantee: if an exception is thrown, the
>   object is in a valid state. It throws an exception of member type
>   failure if the resulting error state flag is not goodbit and member
>   exceptions was set to throw for that state. Any exception thrown by an
>   internal operation is caught and handled by the function, setting
>   badbit. If badbit was set on the last call to exceptions, the function
>   rethrows the caught exception.

So it will only throw `failure` exceptions, if you have set `exceptions` to allow this. It will also only throw underlying exceptions if you have allowed it to.

If you want fine grained control, read about [exception masks](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/).